# how to ssh a loop over several commands

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh, command

I am new to ssh so forgive me if my questions are trivial..i need to make a a remote computer execute a set of commands several times so i was thinking about making a loop using ssh ..the problem is i don't know do i save those commands in a file and loop on that file or can i like save them in ssh and just call them ..i am really troubled..also if i make a loop like this

```
i= 10
while i!= 0 
execute command.text file ???
i--
```

How to i tell it to execute the file ?

Answer (score 0):

Just try first on the shell in the remote machine to run the command you want.

You will find plenty of info over the internet about loops in shell/bash/csh/whatevershell:

For instance assuming bash run in the remote host (from: http://www.bashoneliners.com/ )

```
$ for ((i=1; i<=10; ++i)); do echo $i; done
```

Once you learn that, simply then take that statement to the ssh command from the machine you want to trigger the action:

```
$ ssh user@remotehost 'for ((i=1; i<=10; ++i)); do echo $i; done'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple script that will execute needed commands, and path it to ssh.
For example:

script.sh, it will iterate over your bunch of commands 10 times:

```
for i in $(seq 10)
do
 command1
 command2
 command3
done
```

and path it to remote server for execution:
`$ ssh $SERVERNAME < script.sh`

Answer (score 0):

If you have this `command.text` file in which you have written all the commands in column (you can modify them with vi or vim and put them in column), you don't even need to do a loop, you can simply do:

`cat command.text | awk '{print "ssh user@remotehost "$0" "}' | sh -x`

For example if `command.text` contains:

```
ls -lart 
cd /tmp
uname -a
```

This will let you do all commands written in the `command.text` by doing `ssh user@remotehost`.